# Macro expansion is done in which phase of a compiler?

Tags: compilers

This is question raised by my teacher in the class room. I don't have enough knowledge about phases of compiler and macro expansion. Could someone help me in finding out proper solution to this

Comment: You should probably review your class notes, or do some independent research. The question may also not have a universal answer. Also, what are macros, in general?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's completely dependent on the language. Different languages have wildly different notions of macros. I'll just give a few examples; other situations are possible.

#### The original C language (K&R C)

Macros are expanded by the preprocessor, which is a separate program that runs before the compiler proper. Macros perform a simple text substitution. This program prints `1`, because `PLUS()PLUS()` expands to `++` which is the increment operator.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define PLUS() +
int main()
{
    int x = 0;
    PLUS()PLUS()x;
    printf("%d\n", x);
    return 0;
}
```

#### The modern C language (ANSI C)

Macros are expanded by the preprocessor, which acts on tokens, after lexical analysis. Thus, a macro only expands to whole tokens, but can contain things like unbalanced parentheses. The program above prints 0, because each `PLUS()` expands to a `+` token, so the instruction is equivalent to `+ + x;`.

#### Lisp

Macros act on the program's representation as an abstract syntax tree, i.e. after parsing. Thus a macro expands to a sexp (Lisp's term for an abstract syntax tree), and its arguments are themselves sexps. Macros are expanded before variable resolution. Such macros are said to be [unhygienic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hygienic_macro). Care must be taken not to mix up variables introduced by a macro from the variables of the program fragments.

```
(defmacro repeat (count func)
  `(loop for i from 1 to ,count
      do (apply ,func nil)))
(repeat 3 (lambda () (print "hello")))
(let ((i 5))
  (repeat 3 (lambda () (print i))))
```

The first call to `repeat` prints `hello` three times as expected. The second call to `repeat` does not print `5` three times, it prints `1` then `2` then `3`, because the variable `i` from the macro shadows the variable `i` from the context of the macro call.

#### Scheme

Scheme is similar to Lisp, but with a few differences. One of the differences is that Scheme macros are hygienic. The Scheme equivalent of the program above prints `hello` three times then `5` three times.

```
(define-syntax repeat
  (syntax-rules ()
    ((repeat count func)
     (do ((i 1 (+ 1 i)))
         ((> i count))
       (func)))))
(repeat 3 (lambda () (display "hello") (newline)))
(let ((i 5))
  (repeat 3 (lambda () (display i) (newline))))
```

#### TeX

TeX expands macros in its mouth but defines them in its stomach. But don't set too much store by this: from a language design perspective, TeX is weird.

Comment: The shape of this answer suggests that this question should not be here. Can you suggest a better site for it?

Comment: @Raphael The question could live on either [cs.se] or [so], but I think SO wouldn't do it justice. This is fundamentally a science question, but one for which the answer happens to be “there's no real scientific foundation to it”. That's my first sentence, but it would make for a pretty boring answer if I didn't illustrate with examples. Analogy: the question “what colors can plants be?” calls for a biology answer that discusses clorophyll. A natural follow-up question could be “what colors can birds be?” which doesn't have any similar answer (or would it discuss plumage and mating?).

Answer (score 0):

Macro expansion is done by a preprocessor before the compiler ever looks at the file. This is at least how it works in C/C++.

Comment: This is not how it works in Clang. (It's also, obviously, not how it works in Common Lisp, Dylan, Rust, Julia...)

Comment: Arc even does macro expansion at run-time!